# Laravel pagination with raw query

Tags: pagination, laravel-8

When I put pagination(50); it shows WhereNull does not exist. and then I go make the whereNull into ctrl + /

and it show the next line which is OrderBy not exist. I seriously dont know where the problem is.. because I want to make pagination without using datatable from a DB::raw query.....

```
 public function searchParticipation(Request $request){

    ini_set('memory_limit','2G');

    if ($request->method() != 'POST') {
        return redirect()->route('ticketparticipation.view');
    }

    $replaceStartDate = $this->remove_string($request['start_date']);
    $replaceEndDate = $this->remove_string($request['end_date']);

    $valStartDate = strtotime($replaceStartDate) + (60*60*8);
    $valEndDate = strtotime($replaceEndDate) + (60*60*24) + (60*60*8) - 1;

    $event_id = $request['event_id'];
    $category_id = $request['category_id'];
    $ticket_number = $request['ticket_number'];
    $full_name = $request['full_name'];

    $dataEvent = array(
        'event_id' => $event_id,
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'ticket_number' => $ticket_number
    );

    $superadmins = User::UserOrganizer()->get();

    $user_id = Session::get('user_id');
    $roles = Session::get('roles');

    if(empty(Session::get('roles'))){
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/admin/logout2');
    }

    $eventx = Event::query();

    $eventx = $eventx->select('id', 'name');

    if ($roles == 'Organizer-Admin') {
        $eventx->Where('admin_id','=',$user_id);
        $event = $eventx->Where('is_deleted','=','0')->get(); //->Where('is_active','=','1')
    }elseif($roles == 'Organizer-Project'){
        $eventx->Where('project_manager_id','=',$user_id);
        $event = $eventx->Where('is_deleted','=','0')->get(); //->Where('is_active','=','1')
    }elseif($roles == 'Organizer-Super-Admin'){
        $eventx->Where('superadmin_id','=',$user_id);
        $event = $eventx->Where('is_deleted','=','0')->get(); //->Where('is_active','=','1')
    }elseif($roles == 'Superadmin-Organizer'){
        $event = $eventx->Where('is_deleted','=','0')->get(); //->Where('is_active','=','1')
    }


    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'roles' => $roles,
        'date_start' => $request['start_date'],
        'date_end' => $request['end_date']
    );

    if($data['roles'] == 'Organizer-Admin'){
        $field = "event.admin_id";
    }elseif($data['roles'] == 'Organizer-Project'){
        $field = "event.project_manager_id";
    }else{
        $field = "event.superadmin_id";
    }

    $tCount = EventParticipation::Select('event_participation.id')
        ->join('event', 'event.id', '=', 'event_participation.event_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', 'event_participation.run_id');
    if($event_id != ''){
        $tCount = $tCount->Where("event_participation.event_id", "=", $event_id);
    }
    if($category_id != ''){
        $tCount = $tCount->Where("event_participation.run_id", "=", $category_id);
    }
    if($ticket_number != ''){
        $tCount = $tCount->Where(DB::raw('concat(event.ticket_number_prepend,"",event_participation.queue_id)') , '=' , $ticket_number);
    }
    if($full_name != ''){
        $tCount = $tCount->Where("event_participation.full_name", 'LIKE' , '%'.$full_name.'%');
    }

    $tCount = $tCount->Where("event_participation.acceptance_date", "<>", 0)
        ->Where("event_participation.is_participating", "=", 1)
        ->Where("event_participation.is_deleted", "=", 0)
        ->OrderBy('event_participation.creation_date','ASC')
        ->get();


    $eventDetail = Event::Select('name', 'registration_end', 'type','primary_currency')->Where('id', '=', $event_id)->first();

    if($tCount->count() < 10000) {

        $ticketParticipation = EventParticipation::Select(
            DB::raw("if(epu.full_name is not null, epu.full_name, event_participation.full_name) as full_name"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.address is not null, epu.address, event_participation.address) as address"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.city is not null, epu.city, event_participation.city) as city"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.postcode is not null, epu.postcode, event_participation.postcode) as postcode"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.state is not null, epu.state, event_participation.state) as state"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.country is not null, epu.country, event_participation.country) as country"),
            DB::raw("if(epu.additional_info is not null, epu.additional_info, event_participation.additional_info) as additional_info"),
            'event_participation.id', 'event_participation.delivery_company', 'event_participation.tracking_number', 'event_participation.run_id','event_participation.event_id', 'event_participation.local_transaction_number', 'event_participation.user_id',
            'event_participation.nric_passport', 'event_participation.gender', 'event_participation.tshirt_size', 'event_participation.nationality',
            'event_participation.email', 'event_participation.contact_number', 'event_participation.emergency_contact_name', 'event_participation.emergency_contact_number', 'event_participation.medical_conditions', 'event_participation.amount',
            'event_participation.after_discount', 'event_participation.discount_id', 'event_participation.payment_type', 'event_participation.remarks',
            'event.name AS eventname', 'event.ticket_number_prepend', 'categories.title AS run_title', 'event_participation.date_of_birth', 'event_participation.creation_date', 'event_participation.acceptance_date',
            DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(`event_participation`.`creation_date`,\"%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p\") AS `register_date`"),
            DB::raw("CONCAT(event.`ticket_number_prepend`, '', event_participation.`queue_id`) AS `ticket_number`"),
            'virtual_parcel_shipping_order.awb_id','virtual_parcel_shipping_order.awb_url','virtual_parcel_shipping_order.tracking_url','virtual_parcel_shipping_order.shipping_status',
            'virtual_parcel_shipping_order.pick_up_date','virtual_parcel_shipping_order.parcel_content',
            'virtual_parcel_shipping_order.status','virtual_parcel_shipping_order.response')//DB::raw("FROM_UNIXTIME(`event_participation`.`date_of_birth`,\"%d-%m-%Y\") AS `dob`"),
        ->join('event', 'event.id', '=', 'event_participation.event_id')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', 'event_participation.run_id')
            ->leftjoin('event_participation_report_status','participation_id','event_participation.id')
             ->leftjoin('virtual_parcel_shipping_order','participant_id','event_participation.id')
             ->leftjoin('event_participation_utf8 as epu', 'event_participation.id', 'epu.participation_id')->paginate(50);  <<<<<<<< got problem when I add in paginate(50)
        if($event_id != ''){
            $ticketParticipation = $ticketParticipation->Where("event_participation.event_id", "=", $event_id);
        }
        if($category_id != ''){
            $ticketParticipation = $ticketParticipation->Where("event_participation.run_id", "=", $category_id);
        }
        if($ticket_number != ''){
            $ticketParticipation = $ticketParticipation->Where(DB::raw('concat(event.ticket_number_prepend,"",event_participation.queue_id)') , '=' , $ticket_number);
        }
        if($full_name != ''){
            $ticketParticipation = $ticketParticipation->Where("event_participation.full_name", 'LIKE' , '%'.$full_name.'%');
        }

        $ticketParticipation = $ticketParticipation->Where("event_participation.acceptance_date", "<>", 0)
            ->Where("event_participation.is_participating", "=", 1)
            ->Where("event_participation.is_deleted", "=", 0)
            ->WhereNull("event_participation_report_status.participation_id")
            ->OrderBy('event_participation.queue_id', 'DESC')
            ->get()->chunk(1000);

        $eventDiscount = EventDiscountCode::Select('id', 'event_id', 'amount', 'code')->Where('event_id', $event_id)->get();
        
        return view('admin.organizer.participant_summary',['ticketParticipation'=>$ticketParticipation], compact('event', 'ticketParticipation', 'eventDiscount', 'dataEvent', 'eventDetail'));
    }else{

        return view('admin.organizer.participant_summaryv2', compact('event','data', 'dataEvent', 'eventDetail'));

    }

}
```

I am seriously not sure where is the problem.....

Comment: Please show your real code, I do not find the pagination(50) in your current code.

Comment: because I am not sure how to add it in.. there is no much example on how to manually paginate on website...

Comment: Please add it to your code in a way that you think is the best according to your current knowledge. That will help me understand what the exact intention is. Or, if you want to discuss the exact code that you have shared, then edit your question, remove references to pagination and add your current error. I'm happy to help, but before that we need to absolutely clarify the problem.

Comment: ->leftjoin('event_participation_utf8 as epu', 'event_participation.id', 'epu.participation_id')->paginate(50);  <<<<<<<< got problem when I add in paginate(50) is it like this? It;s in the question...

Comment: Is the error message telling you that paginate does not exist when you call it?

Comment: it shows me it shows WhereNull does not exist.

Comment: `WhereNull` is at a totally different place and you have successfully called `Where` a few times in between. Can you confirm?